# Why am i getting this error when i try to delete a post?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-delete

for school i have to make a online portfolio with a cms. for the most part it is going well, but when i try to add a delete function, so a admin can delete a post i get a error from google chrome: Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfoliojbehrens\admin\delete.php on line 4.
the code :

delete.php:

```
 <?php
include_once("../includes/functions.php");
sec_session_start();
  deletePost($mysqli, $id).($_GET['id']);
?>
```

and the functions page of this:

```
function getAdminPosts($mysqli)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $post = array();

    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $post[] = $row;
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['author']."</td><td><a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Delete</a><br /><a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['id']. "\">Edit</a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
function deletePost($mysqli, $id){
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE ID = $id";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    return true;
    header("Location: ../admin/posts.php");
}
```

i hope u can help me with this

Comment: First of all, what is the `.` after `deletePost()`?

Comment: with that i try to get the id from the url. but seeing your post i guess its not the correct way to do it. @BenM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `deletePost()` just sets a header to the `posts.php` page. You're trying to access `$id` which is never defined.

Update `delete.php` as follows:

```
include_once("../includes/functions.php");
sec_session_start();
deletePost($mysqli, $_GET['id']);
```

Comment: can u help me also on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080933/why-doesnt-it-want-to-add-a-category/21080952?noredirect=1#21080952